# Why does (not false and true or not false and not true) come out to True?

Tags: boolean-logic

Why does (not false and true or not false and not true) come out to True?

If we evaluate in order, from left to right, we will have an and statement at the end with a not true. Shouldn't this come out to false?

Comment: `not false and true` -> `true and true` -> `true`. `true or <whatever>` -> `true`.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError   How do you know it is true or <whatever> rather than 
true or not false -> true.   true and not true --> false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because operator precedence.

Check the documentation for the operators in the language you're using to see their specific rules.  But at least in every language I've used the `and` operation takes precedence over the `or` operation.

So this:

```
not false and true or not false and not true
```

Is the same as this:

```
(not false and true) or (not false and not true)
```

The `not` operation has even higher precedence, so now it's the same as this:

```
((not false) and true) or ((not false) and (not true))
```

Which reduces to:

```
(true and true) or (true and false)
```

Which reduces to:

```
true or false
```

Which reduces to:

```
true
```